# Can you use Swift as a web programming language?

Tags: swift

Could you technically use Swift as a programming language for building a website / web app?

---

Update: Looks like a lot of people are working on this.

- https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect
- https://github.com/glock45/swifter
- https://github.com/grzegorzleszek/HTTPSwiftServer
- https://github.com/izqui/Taylor
- https://github.com/crossroadlabs/express
- https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura
- https://github.com/vapor/vapor

---

Official support from Apple: https://swift.org/server-apis/

Comment: Maybe take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417816/how-popular-is-c-for-making-websites-web-applications. The idea is similar. Plus, you would need the LLVM compiler (but you might be able to get away with GCC, not sure)

Comment: Theoretically any language could be a web programming language. The browser just needs to understand the output that it's receiving. With that in mind you could technically use swift, write a custom compiler to run on typical web servers and mess around to get it to work but I'd ask- why bother? Php and asp do the job pretty well and are well supported. Adding swift or others into the mix just makes your projects more costly in time, devs and money

Comment: Right. That's what I figured: anything technically could work, but why when there are much better alternatives? Well, I guess one reason would be for speed. I don't have any benchmarks, but if Swift was faster it might make a better choice. Also, if you're shop is primarily an iOS shop, then you could learn just one language... The small community and lack of development in the area might be a detriment.

Comment: It's a valid point but a moot one in a business sense. App dev teams aren't suited for web dev (standards, common functionality etc) and are quite costly. For the same price as 1 good, legit iOS dev, developing a custom compiler, and probably rewriting a lot of the core functions of PHP/ASPX I can hire 5 great PHP guys AND a front end designer- and the job will probably be done much quicker. Theoretically though, sure. And don't get me wrong- I absolutely love disruption but I fear there's a LOT of movement needed before this could work.

Comment: May be of relevance: https://github.com/izqui/Taylor

Comment: All of the links are leading to source implementing *new* httpd. In practice, working CGI or FCGI on a standard httpd (Apache, Nginx), is more versatile. Since apple has now (12/03/15) open sourced the foundation library (https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation), this is feasible under OSX *and* Linux.

Comment: Kitura and Vapor appear to be gaining some traction (5k and 9k github stars respectively at present)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In theory, of course.

Any program that can output plain text can also be used for CGI(Common Gateway Interface) which includes Swift as well.

Therefore, yes, you can use Swift for web programming. <s>However, currently, there are no additional libraries(like there are in PHP or EJB/JSP) to make this process easy for you.</s> Take a look at some popular web frameworks for Swift such as [Vapor](https://github.com/vapor/vapor).

Comment: This would be a very interesting project I think!  With middleware and all that crap.

Comment: "Maybe you can start making these facilities by yourself." :)

Comment: Given the recent announcement of Swift becoming open source and the compiler being available for Linux, this takes a completely new turn. What you really miss now is a solid application framework, like Django or ASP.NET. The moment something like this arise, swift would be my first choice.

Comment: Did someone say "swift on rails" :O?

Comment: Swift 2 is now open source and can run on Linux/OS X all we need now is a web application framework for swift and the ability to run it on windows so swift can become a powerful language :D

Answer (score 26):

Not sure how active this topic is anymore, but in case anyone finds this in the future, I'd like to announce here that I have started working on a framework for writing FastCGI applications in Swift.

Of course you can use any Objective-C web framework (though there are rather few), and you can certainly use Swift as a scripting language to dump out HTML strings to be regurgitated by CGI. However, (I'm going to get all philosophical here) I think that settling for such an approach is not very "Swift-like" if I dare use the term. The Swift designers went through a lot of trouble to make sure that it's more than "just" Obj-C without the (constraints of) C (in fact, I *almost* wish they hadn't said that since it's so often misquoted). Swift is also much closer to the functional family than Obj-C (while still retaining solid object orientation AND managing to add Python-esque scriptability). This opens up a whole new world of design choices that I think need to be explored. Also, type safety... but I digress...

All this to say, I've taken it upon myself to create a modular "microframework" that will let you write web apps in Swift at a very high level. At the time of this writing, I'd classify it as a functional proof of concept, but it's still not as abstract as I'd like and is missing a number of key features that would be necessary for real-world use. Contributions are of course welcome. Hope somebody finds this helpful. https://github.com/ianthetechie/SwiftCGI

Comment: I found this very helpful. Great post.

Comment: I love swift so much and I love what you are doing! I'd like to help you out with this.

Answer (score 24):

Swift works just perfect as a web programming language. You can do python like scripting (for rapid development or simple tasks) and later compile the same code with XCode (for speed):

Copy the following script to /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/TestCGI on your Mac (OSX Mavericks or Yosemite with Xcode 6.x installed). Make it executable with `chmod +x TestCGI`. With httpd started call `http://localhost/cgi-bin/TestCGI`. You will get the call parameters echoed...

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift

import Foundation

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print("Content:")
print("")
print("1. Process.argument(s):<br />")
for s in Process.arguments {
    print(s + "<br />")
}
print("<br />")

let env: Dictionary = NSProcessInfo().environment

if let requestMethod = env["REQUEST_METHOD"] {
    print("2. Request method is: \(requestMethod)<br /><br />")
}

print("3. Number of environment variables: \(env.count)<br /><br />")

print("4. List environment:<br />")
for key in env.keys {
    print("\(key) == \(env[key]!)<br />")
}
```

Apple has now (12/03/15) open sourced the Foundation library (https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation) to allow compilation on *Linux Servers*.

Comment: it just prints content of TestCGI for me

Comment: you have to enable CGI module /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to make it work

Comment: How does it work on a server other than a Mac?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/swift` (or the path shown by `shell> which swift`) can be used instead of `xcrun`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

Swift does the same as ObjectiveC, but does it easier. Therefore, you could use a very simple CGI-Interface (see http://www.sveinbjorn.org/objectivecgi) to analyse and answer client requests (both GET and POST) on the server side.

Since Swift is strong in string manipulation, it will be somewhere between ObjectiveC and PHP/Perl in terms of abstraction. For many purposes, a SQLite or MySQL frontend isn't even needed. Just drop your data into some text file on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create web apps in Swift. [Tailor](https://tailorframe.work/) is one of the web frameworks which allows you to do that. Its source code is on [Github](https://github.com/brownleej/tailor).

Comment: Tailor seems something really interesting. Thanks for mention.

Answer (score 1):

As per the other answers, you can use Apple Swift in any number of ways as part of a web site/app implementation.

Additionally however, other companies are also developing Swift language compilers which extend the capabilities even further.  For example, [RemObjects recently announced](http://blogs.remobjects.com/blogs/mh/2014/07/24/p6903) that in the next major release of their Elements compiler, they would be introducing a new compiler front-end dubbed "Silver", which is a Swift compiler.

As a front end onto their existing compiler technology which already supports ObjectPascal (Oxygene) and C# (Hydrogene), this means that you will be able to develop .NET and Java applications (including Android) using the Swift language.  With .NET support, that obviously means you could use Swift to create an ASP.NET web site/app.

Note that this is a native compiler for each platform - there is no source code translation/cross compilation or platform abstraction or compatibility framework involved, as there is with (for example) Xamarin.  The RemObjects compiler produces platform specific, native code (i.e. MSIL for .NET, Java Bytecode for JVM etc etc).  It also allows the developer to consume platform libraries natively.  i.e. when developing for Cocoa, Cocoa classes are exposed directly into the language, ditto Java classes when developing for Java, .NET framework for .NET etc.

This is the case whether you are using the ObjectPascal, C# or Swift language front-ends (and you can mix and match languages in a project, if you so desire).

The 8.0 release has been in beta for a while already so existing Elements licensee's have been playing with it already.  :)

Comment: Silver is quite different from Apple Swift I believe due to dependence on JVM/CLR. Garbage collection and all that.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "Quite different".  None of the differences that I am aware of are due specifically to GC (though there may be some differences here that require differences in coding *practices* in some cases, as opposed to differences in the *language* per se).  Also Silver has *extensions* (w.r.t Swift) to make the language "play nice" (or **more** nice :)) on JVM/CLR, but you don't *have* to use those extensions.  Full info here:  http://docs.elementscompiler.com/Silver/DifferencesAndLimitations/

Comment: There are more considerations such as lack of Cocoa Frameworks. You'll be writing either JVM or .NET flavored Swift. It might be the same language, but it's not as if you could just copy it over from say Windows to Mac.

Answer (score 1):

In the article Cocoa with Love, you could find an example of HTTP server. It is written in Obj-C:
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html

Here is my attempt to create a swift version:
https://github.com/grzegorzleszek/HTTPSwiftServer

Browsing the web, I've found really nice swift version of HTTP server. It is worth to have a look:
https://github.com/glock45/swifter